# Notification with multiple buttons

Tags: android, notifications

I need to display notification with two buttons. Different operation need to perform for each button.so for that I have written following code but when I'm getting multiple notification delete action is not performing.

```
Random NOTIFICATION_ID = new Random();
int CANCELNOTIFICATIONID = NOTIFICATION_ID.nextInt();
// define sound URI, the sound to be played when there's a notification
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Log.i("******* Service6", "" + msg);
// intent triggered, you can add other intent for other actions
Intent intent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, LoginActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GcmIntentService.this, 0, intent, 0);


Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, DeleteArchiveLoopActivity.class);
deleteIntent.putExtra(LoopMeConstants.EXTRA_DELETE_ARCHIVE_LOOPS, "Delete loops");
Trace.i(TAG, "Looptype Delete loop");
deleteIntent.putExtra("DELETE_ARCHIVE_LOOP_ID", loopId);
deleteIntent.putExtra("NOTIFICATONID", CANCELNOTIFICATIONID);
deleteIntent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
//            PendingIntent pDeleteIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 145623, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Intent archiveIntent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, DeleteArchiveLoopActivity.class);
Trace.i(TAG, "Looptype Archive loop");
archiveIntent.putExtra(LoopMeConstants.EXTRA_DELETE_ARCHIVE_LOOPS, "Archive loops");
archiveIntent.putExtra("DELETE_ARCHIVE_LOOP_ID", loopId);
archiveIntent.putExtra("NOTIFICATONID", CANCELNOTIFICATIONID);
archiveIntent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
//            PendingIntent pArchiveIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 145623, archiveIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Sample");
notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mPushtext));
notificationBuilder.setContentText(mPushtext);
notificationBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.delete, "Delete", PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 145623, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));
notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.archive, "Archive", PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 145623, archiveIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);

//            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pArchiveIntent);
Log.i("GCMIntent Srevice5", "" + msg);
notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
mNotificationManager.notify(CANCELNOTIFICATIONID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

How to solve this issue.

Comment: i think you are setting intent 2 time in addAction and your delete intent is overwrite by your archiveintent

Comment: @VishalGaur for different actions we need to write different intents.

Comment: so the "archive" action is working?

Comment: @0X0nosugar I changed the code as mentioned in the below answer now both are working

Comment: That's good. -  I was wondering whether it was the "FLAG_ONE_SHOT" in the delete action which made it work just once.

Comment: @0X0nosugar what you said it works only once.with the use of the mentioned code below i solved the issue.Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below way i have solved it.

in the intent i have given two differentactivities

```
 Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, DeleteLoopActivity.class);

 Intent archiveIntent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, ArchiveLoopActivity.class);

notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.delete, "Delete", PendingIntent.getActivity(this, CANCELNOTIFICATIONID, deleteIntent, 0));
notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.archive, "Archive", PendingIntent.getActivity(this, CANCELNOTIFICATIONID, archiveIntent, 0));
```

The above code solves my problem
Thanks all

Answer (score 15):

You need to use different requestCode in [Pending intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))

```
notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.delete, "Delete", PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));
notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.archive, "Archive", PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2, archiveIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Comment: If i give different requestCode also it is not working.It is working only for one notification.

Comment: Try to use random differen request codes for different notifications